# Convert any angle to the interval [ -pi , pi ]

Tags: python, numpy, trigonometry, angle

How to convert the value of one arbitrary angle `x`, in radians, from the interval **]-infinite, infinite[** to the equivalent angle in the interval **[-pi , pi]**?

Examples of such a conversion, in degrees:

- 45 deg => 45 deg
- 180 deg => 180 deg
- 181 deg => -179 deg
- -200 deg => 160 deg
- 380 deg => 20 deg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have access to at least version 3.7 of Python, then the `math` module has a function [`math.remainder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.remainder) that does exactly what you want in a single function call. Just use `math.remainder(my_angle, 2*math.pi)` (or for fun, use [`math.tau`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.tau) instead of `2 * math.pi`).

Example:

```
>>> from math import remainder, tau
>>> math.remainder(2.7, tau)
2.7
>>> math.remainder(3.7, tau)  # note wraparound to 3.7 - 2*pi
-2.583185307179586
>>> math.remainder(1000.0, tau)
0.9735361584457891
```

Answer (score 1):

Input domain **]-inf, inf[**:

```
a1 = np.array([45, 180, 181, -200, 380, -721])
```

Output domain **]-180, 180[**:

```
a2 = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(np.sin(np.deg2rad(a1)), np.cos(np.deg2rad(a1))))
print(a2)  # [45., 180., -179., 160., 20., -1.]
```

Output domain **]0, 360[**:

```
a3 = [i if i>=0 else i+360 for i in a2]
print(a3)  # [45., 180., 181., 160., 20., 359.]
```